# 3D Texture sampling perpendicular to primitive

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl

I'm implementing a slice-based volume renderer - i.e. my volumetric data is in a 3D texture, and I have a stack of proxy geometry that is rendered to sample the data.

I would like to know whether there is a way to specify the size of a fragment in texels perpendicular to the plane of a primitive.

For example my geometry is axis aligned like this:

- a stack of 200 planes (quads) with the bottom left at (-1, -1, z) and the top right at (1, 1, z)
- where z is from -1 to 1 with a step size of 0.01
- the texture coordinate is `(gl_Position.xyz + 1) / 2`

If I understand texture sampling correctly, the selection of `MIN_FILTER` or `MAG_FILTER` in the xy/st direction should happen automatically depending on the size of a fragment in texels since they are on the same primitive.

How can I set the 'size' of a fragment in texels in the z/p direction? Working with the above example, I would like to interpolate between samples using `MAG_FILTER` if I have more slices than texture sample points in the Z direction, and using `MIN_FILTER` if I have fewer slices.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering modes are specified only for `x`, `y` and not `z`. The trilinear filtering modes interpolate across different mipmap levels. Perhaps what you really are intending to do, can be achieved with a 3D texture using `texImage3D()`?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding as to what kind of trilinear filtering I want (see notes [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Filtering)). I am after linear filtering along three dimensions, not bilinear filtering + filtering between mipmaps.

Comment: That is what I implied - "Perhaps what you really are intending to do, can be achieved with a 3D texture using texImage3D() ?" -  GL_LINEAR maps to trilinear in a 3D texture. There is no concept of a MIN/MAG *across* 2D primitives in Z direction that I am aware of.

Comment: I am already using texImage3D (code to follow shortly, should've known better than posting without it but even a minimal example is fairly huge). I am trying to give my primitives 'depth' from a sampler perspective, so bits of the texture between slices are sampled correctly - does that make sense?

Comment: Have you used the "bias" parameter in the texture3D sampler ?

Comment: No, isn't `bias` to do with sampling between mipmaps? I don't want to do this since the sampling in Z might be different to the XY sampling. For example if I have a very low number of slices and a large viewport resolution, I will need to either use MIN_FILTER or sample a small mipmap in Z and use MAG_FILTER and sample a large mipmap in XY.

Comment: On closer examination, I think I will have to implement my own interpolation using `textureOffset`, since according to [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml) using GL_LINEAR for MIN_FILTER only samples the closest 4 points - this means it cannot work for 3D sampling in the way I was hoping for, since that would require at least 6 sample points.